# React, Javascript export functions from loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a file right now with functions like this:

```
export const setSomething = something => setStore(SOMETHING_CONSTANT, something);
export const setSomething1 = something1 => setStore(SOMETHING_CONSTANT_1, something1);
export const setSomething2 = something2 => setStore(SOMETHING_CONSTANT_2, something2);
```

I constantly add new functions, so I want to make an array and generate this functions based on this array, like this:

```
const setters = [
  ['setSomething', SOMETHING_CONSTANT],
  ['setSomething1', SOMETHING_CONSTANT_1],
  ['setSomething2', SOMETHING_CONSTANT_2],
]
```

I know I can make an object with the functions and export that object but that would make me refactor a lot more code where I import these functions. Is there a way to export functions based on a loop?

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't. ECMAScript modules are meant to be statically analyzable and the `export` clauses must be on top-level of a file.